# ng-bootstrap drop down menu does not seem to work with *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

The Dropdown menu is supposed to dynamically populate a list of languages. I tried using ngFor to do this but none of the list items appear in the dropdown menu except for the first one:

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div *ngIf="data.enableLanguageList && data.languageList?.length > 0" class="row">
    <div ngbDropdown class="col d-inline-block">
      <button ngbDropdownToggle 
              class="btn btn-success btn-lg dropdown-toggle" 
              id="languageSelect">
        <strong> Lang - {{ data.currentLanguage }} </strong>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu 
           *ngFor="let lang of data.languageList;" 
            class="dropdown-menu" 
            aria-labelledby="languageSelect">
        <button ngbDropdownItem 
                class="dropdown-item" 
                [ngClass] = "[lang === data.currentLanguage ? 'active' : '']" 
                (click) = "setLanguage(lang)">
             <h5> <strong> {{ lang }} </strong> </h5>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is your service delivering any data? What does `data.languageList` contains?

Comment: btw, it does not seems correct to use <h5> for the button text. it would be very confusing for screen readers. `h` tags are for headings. some tools, including screen readers, build a table of content based on `h` tags

Comment: similar issue with `strong` tag when it is used only for styling (like here, I suppose)

Answer (score 2):

You applied `ngFor` to `ngbDropdownMenu` while needed to create in a loop several `ngbDropdownItem`s

```
      <div ngbDropdownMenu 
            class="dropdown-menu" 
            aria-labelledby="languageSelect">
        <button ngbDropdownItem 
                *ngFor="let lang of data.languageList;" 
                class="dropdown-item" 
                [ngClass] = "[lang === data.currentLanguage ? 'active' : '']" 
                (click) = "setLanguage(lang)">
             {{ lang }}
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ul`, `li` approach can be used for `ngbDropdown`

```
<div ngbDropdown class="dropdown">
<button ngbDropdownToggle  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
    id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-expanded="false">
    Project A
</button>
<ul ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" >
    <li *ngFor = "let lang of data.languageList">
        <a class="ngbDropdownItem" href="#" style="all:unset">{{lang}}</a>
    </li>                                                              
</ul></div>
```